# Ajax call not getting data which is in json format from API

Tags: asp.net, ajax, api, asp.net-core

I am trying to call api function from asp.net core razor page from news.cshtml page using below ajax function.

Its giving undefined error for `console.log(len);`... if i remove this then nothing happens no data, no error

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "api/news/getallnews/1",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    var len = response.length;
                    console.log(len);
                    var table = $("<table><tr><th>Details</th></tr>");
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                       // console.log("i "+i);
                        table.append("<tr><td>Title:</td><td>" + response[i].newsHeading + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                    table.append("</table>");
                    $("#news").html(table);
                }
            });
```

**json Data returnet by api,** i am just showing one row while my api returns around 36

```
    {"data":[
    {
    "newsID":2076,
"newsHeading":"New Title is here",
    "newsBrief":"New Brief is here",
    "newsDetails":"\u003Cp\u003E\r\n\t\u003Cem\u003E New details in HTML format are here.\u003C/p\u003E\r\n",
    "newsDate":"2020-01-28T00:00:00",
    "languageID":1
    }]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var len = response.data.length;
console.log(len);
```